# RDF/XML format to JSON

Tags: python, json, rdf, xml-parsing

I am trying to convert the RDF/XML format to JSON format. Is there any python (library) example that i can look into for this to do ?

Comment: In case you are here because of the plain title of the question. Look here for a java solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43638342

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [rdflib](http://www.rdflib.net/) to parse many RDF variants (including RDF/XML), or maybe the simpler [rdfparser](http://infomesh.net/2003/rdfparser/) if it suits your needs.  You can then use the standard library Python `json` module (or equivalently third-party `simplejson` if you're using some Python version older than 2.6) to serialize the in-memory structure built with the parser into JSON.  I'm not familiar with any package embodying both steps, unfortunately.

With the example at rdfparser's site, the overall work would be just...:

```
import rdfxml
import json

class Sink(object): 
   def __init__(self): self.result = []
   def triple(self, s, p, o): self.result.append((s, p, o))

def rdfToPython(s, base=None): 
   sink = Sink()
   return rdfxml.parseRDF(s, base=None, sink=sink).result

s_rdf = someRDFstringhere()
pyth = rdfToPython(s_rdf)
s_jsn = json.dumps(pyth)
```

Answer (score 1):

For those coming to this question recently, [rdflib](https://rdflib.readthedocs.io/) since version 6.0 supports JSON-LD output directly:

```
from rdflib import Graph

g = Graph()
g.parse("demo.xml")
print g.serialize(format='json-ld')
```