# How to convert RDF to pretty nested JSON using java rdf4j

Tags: java, json, rdf, json-ld, rdf4j

I have a simple RDF file and want to convert it to nice nested JSON.

```
_:b0 a <http://schema.org/Book> ;
    <http://schema.org/name> "Semantic Web Primer (First Edition)" ;
    <http://schema.org/offers> _:b1 ;
    <http://schema.org/publisher> "Linked Data Tools" .

_:b1 a <http://schema.org/Offer> ;
    <http://schema.org/price> "2.95" ;
    <http://schema.org/priceCurrency> "USD" .
```

should become

```
{
  "type" : "Book",
  "name" : "Semantic Web Primer (First Edition)",
  "offers" : {
    "type" : "Offer",
    "price" : "2.95",
    "priceCurrency" : "USD"
  },
  "publisher" : "Linked Data Tools"
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use framing

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.eclipse.rdf4j.model.Statement;
import org.eclipse.rdf4j.rio.RDFFormat;
import org.eclipse.rdf4j.rio.RDFHandlerException;
import org.eclipse.rdf4j.rio.RDFParser;
import org.eclipse.rdf4j.rio.RDFWriter;
import org.eclipse.rdf4j.rio.Rio;
import org.eclipse.rdf4j.rio.helpers.StatementCollector;
import org.junit.Test;

import com.github.jsonldjava.core.JsonLdOptions;
import com.github.jsonldjava.core.JsonLdProcessor;
import com.github.jsonldjava.utils.JsonUtils;
import com.google.common.base.Charsets;


public class HowToConvertRdfToJson {

    @Test
    public void convertRdfToPrettyJson(){
        try(InputStream in = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("book.ttl")){
            System.out.println(getPrettyJsonLdString(in,RDFFormat.TURTLE));
        }catch(Exception e){
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }   
    
    /**
     * @param in Input stream with rdf data
     * @param format format of the rdf data
     * @return a pretty JSON document as String
     */
    public static String getPrettyJsonLdString(InputStream in, RDFFormat format) {
        return getPrettyJsonLdString(
                readRdfToString(in, format, RDFFormat.JSONLD, ""));
    }

    /**
     * @param statements rdf statements collected
     * @return a pretty JSON document as String
     */
    public static String getPrettyJsonLdString(Collection<Statement> statements) {
        return getPrettyJsonLdString(
                graphToString(statements, RDFFormat.JSONLD));
    }

    private static String getPrettyJsonLdString(String rdfGraphAsJson) {
        try {
        //@formatter:off
                return JsonUtils
                        .toPrettyString(
                             removeGraphArray(
                                getFramedJson(
                                        createJsonObject(
                                                        rdfGraphAsJson))));
        //@formatter:on
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
    
    private static Map<String, Object> removeGraphArray(Map<String, Object> framedJson) {
        List<Map<String,Object>> graph = (List<Map<String, Object>>) framedJson.get("@graph");
        return graph.get(0);
    }

    private static Map<String, Object> getFramedJson(Object json) {
        try {
            return JsonLdProcessor.frame(json, getFrame(), new JsonLdOptions());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    private static Map<String, Object> getFrame() {
        Map<String, Object> context = new HashMap<>();
        context.put("@context", "http://schema.org/");
        // if this does not work use the direct address as follows
        // context.put("@context","https://schema.org/docs/jsonldcontext.jsonld");
        return context;
    }

    private static Object createJsonObject(String ld) {
        try (InputStream inputStream =
                new ByteArrayInputStream(ld.getBytes(Charsets.UTF_8))) {
            Object jsonObject = JsonUtils.fromInputStream(inputStream);
            return jsonObject;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
    
    public static Collection<Statement> readRdfToGraph(
            final InputStream inputStream, final RDFFormat inf,
            final String baseUrl) {
        try {
            final RDFParser rdfParser = Rio.createParser(inf);
            final StatementCollector collector = new StatementCollector();
            rdfParser.setRDFHandler(collector);
            rdfParser.parse(inputStream, baseUrl);
            return collector.getStatements();
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public static String readRdfToString(InputStream in, RDFFormat inf,
            RDFFormat outf, String baseUrl) {
        Collection<Statement> myGraph = null;
        myGraph = readRdfToGraph(in, inf, baseUrl);
        return graphToString(myGraph, outf);
    }

    public static String graphToString(Collection<Statement> myGraph,
            RDFFormat outf) {
        StringWriter out = new StringWriter();
        RDFWriter writer = Rio.createWriter(outf, out);
        try {
            writer.startRDF();
            for (Statement st : myGraph) {
                writer.handleStatement(st);
            }
            writer.endRDF();
        } catch (RDFHandlerException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return out.getBuffer().toString();
    }
}
```

Prints

```
{
  "id" : "_:b0",
  "type" : "Book",
  "name" : "Semantic Web Primer (First Edition)",
  "offers" : {
    "id" : "_:b1",
    "type" : "Offer",
    "price" : "2.95",
    "priceCurrency" : "USD"
  },
  "publisher" : "Linked Data Tools"
}
```

With pom

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.rdf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>rdf4j-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.jsonld-java</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsonld-java</artifactId>
        <version>0.10.0</version>
</dependency>
```