# How can I add anonymous individuals in Protege?

Tags: rdf, owl, protege

I want to add a statement in Protege using a blank node. For example, if I expressed it as a Turtle RDF it would be [something like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49726990/how-do-i-add-a-start-and-end-time-to-a-rdf-triple):

```
[
  rdf:type rdf:Statement ;   #this anonymous resource is a Statement... 
  rdf:subject ex:Paul ;      #...with subject Paul
  rdf:predicate ex:running ; #...predicate running
  rdf:object "10miles" ;     #...and object "10miles"
  ex:hasPeriodStart "2018-04-09T10:00:00"^^xsd:dateTime ;
  ex:hasPeriodEnd "2018-04-09T12:00:00"^^xsd:dateTime ;
].
```

Is there a way of doing something similar in Protege (without creating a named individual with an IRI)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Protege does not support blank nodes. One way to achieve something similar is assign a temporary/separate namespace for your blank nodes. I will give you an example of what I mean. Assume I have the following turtle syntax (I left prefixes out to keep this short),

```
:jane :firstname   "Jane";
      :lastname    "Doe";
      :contactInfo [:phonenumber "011 739 4751";
                    :email       "janedoe@examples.com"] .
```

then

```
[:phonenumber "011 739 4751";
 :email       "janedoe@examples.com"]
```

is a blank node. This can be rewritten using a blank node `_:janeContactInfo` as follows:

```
:jane :firstname   "Jane";
      :lastname    "Doe";
      : contactInfo _:janeContactInfo .

 _:janeContactInfo :phonenumber "011 739 4751";
                   :email       "janedoe@examples.com" .
```

This can be represented in Manchester syntax (this is the syntax used in Protege) as:

```
ObjectProperty: contactInfo 
DataProperty: firstname
DataProperty: lastname
DataProperty: phonenumber
DataProperty: email

Individual: jane
Facts:
  ex:firstname, "Jane",
  ex:lastname, "Doe", 
  ex:contactInfo, _janeContactInfo

Individual: _janeContactInfo
Facts:
   ex:phonenumber, "011 739 4751"
   ex:email, "janedoe@examples.com"
```

The `janeContactInfo` individual you can place in a temporary/separate namespace if you want.

Answer (score 2):

There is [RDF-Protege](https://github.com/sszuev/rdf-protege), that is an [ONT-API](https://github.com/owlcs/ont-api/)-based fork, where this is possible via SPARQL tab (via `INSERT` with `BNODE()`). 
Although RDF-Protege is currently a kind of "pet-project" with weak development potential, I hope this functionality could be useful to someone.

[image: sparql tab]

UPD:
Now creation of anonymous individuals is also available on RDF tree tab:
[image: rdf triples tab]