# Add Individuals to owl file with SPARQL query

Tags: insert, sparql, owl, protege

i want to insert some individuals into my ontology **owl file (OWL/XML)** with **SPARQL** using **Protege** for example :

`person1` is an **instance** of **class** `person` and has these **object property assertions** : `hasname Alex`, `hasage 26`

**Here is my code**

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX my_onto: <http://www.semanticweb.org/hp/ontologies/2020/5/personOnto.owl#>
    
INSERT DATA
{
   my_onto:person1 rdf:type my_onto:person .
               rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual .
                my_onto:hasname Alex.
                my_onto:hasage 26.

}
```

**But, i had this error :**

```
Caused by: org.openrdf.query.parser.sparql.ast.ParseException: Encountered " "insert" "INSERT "" at line 7, column 1.
Was expecting one of:
    "base" ...
    "prefix" ...
    "select" ...
    "construct" ...
    "describe" ...
    "ask" ...
    
    at org.openrdf.query.parser.sparql.ast.SyntaxTreeBuilder.generateParseException(SyntaxTreeBuilder.java:8943) ~[na:na]
    at org.openrdf.query.parser.sparql.ast.SyntaxTreeBuilder.jj_consume_token(SyntaxTreeBuilder.java:8813) ~[na:na]
    at org.openrdf.query.parser.sparql.ast.SyntaxTreeBuilder.Query(SyntaxTreeBuilder.java:313) ~[na:na]
    at org.openrdf.query.parser.sparql.ast.SyntaxTreeBuilder.QueryContainer(SyntaxTreeBuilder.java:188) ~[na:na]
    at org.openrdf.query.parser.sparql.ast.SyntaxTreeBuilder.parseQuery(SyntaxTreeBuilder.java:31) ~[na:na]
    at org.openrdf.query.parser.sparql.SPARQLParser.parseQuery(SPARQLParser.java:153) ~[na:na]
    ... 42 common frames omitted
```

Comment: SPARQL Plugin doesn't support `UPDATE` or `INSERT` queries.

Comment: In [RDF-Protege](https://github.com/sszuev/rdf-protege/wiki) this functionality is available through Jena-ARQ. see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58979778/how-can-i-add-anonymous-individuals-in-protege

Comment: @StanislavKralin thank you for the information