# How can I read a JSON-LD in java?

Tags: java, json-ld

I have a file with `json-ld` data. This data corresponds with an ontology, and I want know how I can get a structure of the data through said ontology.

I want create a program in Java to read this json-ld, create that structure and show the information that I want by screen.

What library can I use, and how can I do all of this?

Comment: [See how to create a MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I think the best JSON-LD library for Java is [jsonld-java](https://github.com/jsonld-java/jsonld-java), but Java - as a strongly-typed language - is not a very good fit to process JSON-LD (or vice versa: JSON-LD is too versatile for strongly-typed languages). You'll have to deal with `Object` return values about everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

Use Apache Jena

http://jena.apache.org

```
Model m = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
m.read ("http://url-of-json-document","JSON-LD");
```

Comment: BTW, Jena itself uses `jsonld-java`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50593107/7879193