# Writing Embedding JSON-LD from Jena

Tags: jena, json-ld

I have a Jena model that I extract from a SPARQL `CONSTRUCT`, I want to translate it into JSON-LD, with the [Embed feature](https://json-ld.org/spec/latest/json-ld-framing/#object-embed-flag), ie, if `person1 knows person2`, I want the `person2` object inside person1, linked by the knows property.

Following examples around ([1](https://github.com/apache/jena/blob/master/jena-arq/src-examples/arq/examples/riot/ExJsonLD.java), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50588066/json-ld-blank-node-to-nested-object-in-apache-jena)), I've managed to do it through the setup of a context object:

```
Model m = SparqlUtils.construct ( sparql, model ); // yeah, I want JSON from a CONSTRUCT-extracted subgraph
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter ();

JsonLDWriteContext ctx = new JsonLDWriteContext ();
JsonLdOptions opts = new JsonLdOptions ();
opts.setEmbed ( "@always" );
ctx.setOptions ( opts );

Map<String, Object> frctx = new HashMap<> ( NamespaceUtils.getNamespaces () ); // this is just a map of prefix->uri

Map<String, String> knows = new HashMap<> ();
knows.put ( "@id", "foaf:knows" );
knows.put ( "@type", "@id" );
frctx.put ( "knows", knows );

frctx.put ( "name", "foaf:name" );

Map<String, Object> frame = new HashMap<> ();
frame.put ( "@type", "foaf:Person" );
frame.put ( "@context", frctx ); 
ctx.setFrame ( frame );

Graph graph = m.getGraph ();
PrefixMap prefixes = RiotLib.prefixMap ( graph );
WriterGraphRIOT writer = RDFDataMgr.createGraphWriter ( RDFFormat.JSONLD_FRAME_PRETTY );
writer.write ( sw, graph, prefixes, null, ctx );
```

However, I'm not happy at all with this solution, since I would be just fine with the default '@context', but if I don't set any frame into the `ctx` object that is passed to `write()`, I get an error that the context is missing. On the other hand, if I call `write()` with another format (eg, `JSONLD_COMPACT_PRETTY`), the `ctx` object seems to be ignored by the writer, ie, `@embed = @always` is ignored and the JSON I get is the usual list of flat objects, with the URIs as "knows" values.

How can I do it? Is there a way to get the default context? Is there a simpler way to tell about the embed option?